# Is "one out of ten" plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number

In the following sentence:

> One out of ten people **speaks** (English) as their mother tongue

Is "one out of ten" considered singular, or should **speaks** be changed to **speak**?

Comment: One is one. So singular

Comment: Except notional agreement. So plural.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is definitely singular. If you think about it, 'one' is the subject of the sentence, whilst 'out of ten people' is a subordinate clause and could be separated by commas as in:

'One, out of ten people, speaks English'. 'Two, out of ten people, hate broccoli'.

Comment: Nine point eight out of ten people hate Brussels sprouts. ;-) — ‘Out of ten people’ isn’t a subordinate clause, though—it’s not a clause at all. Truth be told, I’m not sure exactly how to categorize it. ‘Adjunct’ would probably be my best guess, but I’m sure we have some syntacticians here who’ll have a more definite answer.

Comment: It’s not a subordinate clause.

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin *Jack, out of all the children, is good at maths* seems quite the same in structure as *One, out of ten, eats cabbage*. Are you saying that "out of all the children" is not a subordinate clause?

Comment: @WS2 Yes. I see no predicate here.