# "One of the main problems was/were people doing X"

Tags: grammatical-number

In the sentence from the title, is it ***was*** or ***were***?

To me, ***was*** sounds weird because there is a plural form coming right after, but ***were*** also sounds weird because it is *one* problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["1 out of 100 chickens is" or "1 out of 100 chickens are"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42176/1-out-of-100-chickens-is-or-1-out-of-100-chickens-are)

Comment: Another closed duplicate, [Is “one of ten” plural or singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145065/is-one-of-ten-plural-or-singular)

Comment: @Rathony Those questions have either possibility, but this one doesn't. "Was" is the only possible answer here. So we probably shouldn't link it to those questions! :) [Happy New Year btw!]

Comment: @Rathony Reason is that those other two phrases refer to proportions which may refer to a semantically plural amount of things. However, *one of the main problems* only refers to one problem. The word *one* can override plural verb agreement in Subject phrases, but ordinary plural nouns can't override singular verb agreement. I know: it's weird! :)

Comment: @Araucaria Do you mean the second question I linked should not have been closed, either?

Comment: @Rathony I think that one looks like a dupe of the other, so it looks like that close was ok.

Comment: @Araucaria Do you mean that only **was** should be used in the OP's example? I don't think this question has an answer. It's your style and preference. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rathony It is for many similar phrases, but not for this particular one. The subject is both semantically singular and grammatically singular here and a plural common noun can't override this. In this particular example there's no choice :)

Comment: @Araucaria People doing X are one of the main problems is the best answer to this question, I think. BTW, Happy New Year to you, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [It's one of the best \[plural noun\] that + has (or) have](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184634/its-one-of-the-best-plural-noun-that-has-or-have)

Comment: @Nathaniel It looks similar, but it isn't. That question is about how *one* can override a semantically  and grammatically plural Subject. This question is about why a plural common noun can*not* override a semantically a grammatically singular Subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. One of the main problems was the tourists using the wrong passes
> 2. *One of the main problems were the tourists using the wrong passes.(ungrammatical)

The Subject of the first sentence is *one of the main problems*. This noun phrase is grammatically singular. It is also semantically singular. Although the plural word *problems* is next to the verb, this does not affect verb agreement here. Proximity agreement, where the noun phrase nearest the verb can determine the agreement of the verb, sometimes  applies with co-ordinations and lists. For example:

- In the room, there was a double bed, a large drinks cabinet ...

Here the verb seems to be determined by the noun phrase *a double bed* (don't let this fool you into thinking that this is part of the Subject. The Subject of this sentence is the word *there*).

There are also situations where the word *one* in a noun phrase can override the grammatical and semantic plurality of the noun phrase and cause singular verb agreement:

- He's one of those people who always want**s** to have the last word.

There are also situations where a noun phrase is grammatically singular but semantically plural. In these situations either singular or plural verb agreement is grammatical:

- One in ten people loses their wallets on the trip.
- One in ten people lose their wallets on the trip.

Here *one in ten people* is grammatically singular but semantically plural (it doesn't refer to an individual, but the proportion of individuals). The agreement of the verb can be determined either by the grammatical number or the semantic plurality.

However, in the Original Poster's example, the grammatical number of the noun phrase is singular, the noun phrase is also semantically singular. There is no co-ordination or negation to complicate the issue. The plurality of the last noun in the noun phrase cannot override the normal agreement of the verb here.

Incidentally, the example (1) above would sound perfectly natural to nearly all native speakers.

Comment: How do you explain this [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+are+people%2Cthere+is+people%2C+there+were+people%2C+there+was+people&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20were%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20was%20people%3B%2Cc0) results where *are* after there is more broadly used than *is* when a plural noun *people* is used.

Comment: Sentences that start with "there" are called expletive sentences and the subject is not "there".  I wrote a post on these kinds of sentences.  Trouble happens when the subject is compound and people don't know whether to use is or are...."In the room, there are a table and chair."  Most speakers will use "is" because of the proximity of "table."

Comment: @Araucaria it was the best of times and the worst of times.  Where's the subject?

Comment: @michael_timofeev The subject is *it*!

Comment: @michael_timofeev Hi, I opened a chat room so that we don't have to fit our conversation into tiny comment boxes. It's [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33908/grammatical-subjects)

Answer (score 1):

> To me, ***was*** sounds weird because there is a plural form coming right
>   after, but ***were*** also sounds weird because it is one problem.

It could sound weird to you, but that's right.

*One* is a component of your group (*the main problems*) and it is the subject of this sentence.

The sentence is referring indeed to a specific component (*One*) of the plural form, hence the correct form of the verb is the 3rd singular person, that is ***was***.

With *of the main problems*, you're just adding details about which group the subject is part of.

Comment: Dear downvoter, would you at least comment what is the reason of your downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence is '*One of the main problems was people doing X*'. Here, the subject is the problem '*people doing X*' which is singular and hence singular verb '*was*' would be used. It may sound weird because we tend to make verb agree with the immediate subject ('*problems*' in this case).

Comment: The Subject is "One of the problems" ---> "[Was] [one of the main problems] ...." Here you see subject-auxiliary inversion for the question form.

Answer (score 0):

The verb should agree with the subject *one*, so you would say, "One of the main problems *was* people doing X."  The phrase *main problems*, which is where I think you're getting the false sense that you should use *were* instead of *was*, is not actually part of the subject because it is part of a prepositional phrase.  In as much as it may seem to change the number in a subject, a prepositional phrase is never part of the subject and so never changes the number of the subject.  Therefore, despite the seeming plurality of *many problems*, the subject of the sentence remains a singular *one* that agrees with *was* not *were*.

Comment: Nice answer. But the prepositional phrase *is* technically part of the Subject. It's not the  Head word in the Subject phrase. I think that's what you're angling at. :)

Comment: @Araucaria: You're mistaken, a prepositional phrase is never part of the subject.  A prepositional phrase may adjectivally modify a subject, but doing so doesn't make it part of the subject.  You can check any grammar website to verify this.  As an example, Grammar Bytes states: "The subject of a verb will never be part of a prepositional phrase." (http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subject.htm)

Comment: Here's a test for beginner syntax students. If you want to identify the Subject of a declarative sentence change the sentence into an interrogative. The phrase that swaps places with the auxiliary verb is the Subject. "[One of the main problems][ was] people doing X" ---->"[Was][one of the main problems] people doing X?"

Comment: You might find this interesting, btw: [Words, phrases and functions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34099/what-exactly-is-the-word-there-in-an-existential-construction-and-related-que/34172#34172)

Comment: That link you gave has some incorrect information. But its point about prepositional phrases is correct. A Subject is never *part of* a prepositional phrase. This is not at all the same thing as "a prepositional phrase is never part of a Subject" - which is completely untrue.